# shell float number in expr

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get a float number from this :

```
totalmark=$(expr $sum / $subjects )
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

bash doesn't support floats, use awk or bc/dc

eg awk

```
totalmark=$(awk 'BEGIN{print $sum / $subjects}')
```

or bc

```
totalmark=$(echo "scale=2;$sum/$subjects"|bc)
```

if you have the luxury to use different shells other than bash, try zsh or ksh

```
$ zsh -c 'echo $((4/1.3))'
3.0769230769230766

$ ksh -c 'echo $((4/1.3))'
3.07692307692307692
```

Comment: @ghostdog: Fair point, but who has php installed on their client?  Well, in fact, I do see that it is installed by default on Mac OS; I'm sure Apple has its reasons...

Comment: @ghostdog: Since I'm digressing anyway...  It seems to me that not very many years ago that perl -e oneliners were the way most people did these things.  Perl seems to be partly eclipsed these days.

Comment: Thanks for the zsh answer! I couldn't figure out how to do that for some reason.

Comment: which is better and speedly awk or bc ?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z., in either case the great majority of the time is spent starting the tool up -- the time needed to *run* it is relatively small -- and most of that startup time (fork, exec, linker/loader) is involved in *any* external tool, so I wouldn't expect a significant difference (though whether you'll see a difference in practice depends on the specific implementations of awk and bc your operating system ships, which libraries they link to, etc -- so you'd want to benchmark if you really need an answer).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think bash has floating-point capabilities.  You can try:

```
echo "$sum/$subjects" | bc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Try [`bc`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/bc/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
totalmark=$(echo "scale=4;$sum/$subjects"|bc)
```

By the way, three answers say that Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetic. While that is true, `expr` is an external program (`/usr/bin/expr` for me) and it's the one, in particular, in this case which doesn't support floats.

Comment: The GNU `bc` has `scale=0` by default, which the Q presumably doesn't want.  Pass the `-lq` options.

Comment: @Charles: That's why I specified a scale of 4. It could be anything you want. The `--mathlib` option (`-l`) provides a default of `scale=20` (at least on my system with bc 1.06.94). The `--quiet` option is a good idea, though.

Comment: I'm sorry: I had not noticed you had passed the assignment in the input - I must have been daydreaming.  `scale=20` is ruthless overkill, but the wanted information is there, and I tend to prefer noise in the output to noise in the shell script.