# Beginner in shell script

Tags: shell

I am a beginner to shell scripting, so to get used to them I am starting off easy scripts. Trying to calculate the rate of interest for a "principal" amount, I wrote the below shell script.

But I am getting the output as:`(150000*0.8)/100`. I thought I will be getting mathematically solved output which is 1200. `(pr=($principal*$rof)/100)`

Can anyone help me in this? What mistake I have made?

```
principal=150000
rof=0.8
pr=($principal*$rof)/100
echo $pr
```

Comment: You are not choosing the optimal problem to solve in a shell script, the syntax for arithmetic operations is a bit clumsy. If the calculation is the important I would use perl. If learning shell script is important I would do some moving files around instead.

Comment: Thanks. I have a idea to create an alert(like an update) system which needs shell knowledge. The alert comprises of few mathematical calculations too. So, I am trying in like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with this piece of code. Assuming you are using bash, the correct way is shown below,

1. Arithmetic operations are performed with the syntax,
   `x=$(( a + b ))`

   So, for your case, it becomes,
   `pr=$((( principle * rof ) / 100))`
2. It is not possible to perform floating point operations in bash. You can use the unix utility `bc` for such purposes. In your case,
   pr=`bc <<< "( $principle * $rof ) / 100"`

So, your complete code now becomes,

```
#!/bin/bash

principle=150000
rof=0.8

pr=`bc <<< "( $principle * $rof ) / 100"`
echo $pr
```

Answer (score 1):

Bash does not support floating point number aritmetic, [e.g. see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2362611/2838364)

```
$> principle=150000;rof=8;pr=`expr $principle \* $rof / 1000`;echo $pr
1200
```

Comment: In case it worked, accept one answer. Please raise another question if you have a different question.

Comment: Problem is: I couldn't able to access Internet thru laptop. I am doing this via my mobile.

Comment: How is it connected with this question?

Comment: @user3624000 Glad it helped. Please accept the answer for the benefit of others :-)