# confirm numeric character of variable

Tags: bash

I need to do an operation but something is wrong in my code in bash

I have 4 variables,  km1, km2, km3, km4.

I want to sum the 4 variables except when the value is "CLOSED"

```
3.200
CLOSED
1.800
0.600
```

When I do the following sum, there is an error...I thing my variables are not numeric, any help? How can I force them to be numeric and then do the sum?

```
let km=$km1+$km3+$km4
echo $km
```

./sum.sh: line 41: let: km=3.200: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".200")

Comment: Bash does not support floats. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2362611/812912)

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not supported by bash. You can use an external tool like `awk` or `bc`: `km=$( echo "scale=6; $km1+$km3+$km4" | bc)`. You can adjust `scale` according to the required fractional part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shell float number in expr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362154/shell-float-number-in-expr)

Comment: It helps! And If I want to check if km2=CLOSED and take value 0? I  use the following code, but it doesn't take the new value 0  if [ "$km2" == "CLOSED" ]; then $km2=0 fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
km1=3.200
km2=CLOSED
km3=1.800
km4=0.600
total=`LC_ALL=C echo "$km1 $km2 $km3 $km4"|awk '{sum += $1+$2+$3+$4}END {print sum}'`
```

Not that good with awk but i think the above can help. total the is sum of all vars

Comment: Great! What does it make LC_ALL=C ?

Comment: "LC_ALL=C" runs the command line argument in your bash shell. You can ignore it if you are running abash command and not output to awk, if you are passing your output to awk you have to explicitly use this followed by your bash command line.

Comment: @Enric it sets the locale to "C" for the commands on that line, which is probably unnecessary unless yours is set to something else (for example, a European locale that uses `,` instead of `.` for floating point numbers).

Comment: @Tom French.Glad to know this piece of technical info Tom French.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with you code. The first one is that you are trying to work with values other than integers. Bash only does integers. You can round up the values to integers using bc (An arbitrary precision calculator language). The second issue is that you are trying to do math on strings. So consider the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash

km1=3.200;
km2="CLOSED";
km3=1.800;
km4=0.600;

km1=$(echo "$km1/1" | bc)
km3=$(echo "$km3/1" | bc)
km4=$(echo "$km4/1" | bc)

array=($km1 $km2 $km3 $km4)

for i in ${array[@]}; do
 case $i in
 *[0-9]*)
   (( result+=$i ))
 esac
done

echo $result
```

Comment: Clear comments Ravi, interesting way, useful